# Steam opens update box and closes

Tags: 12.04, steam

When I try to open steam with terminal it says this

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-linux:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8967 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_01ADCAAE08B43E5E8AE44675F4157195
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8967 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_01ADCAAE08B43E5E8AE44675F4157195
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 9024 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 9024 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
[1002/173410:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1379786203_client)
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  105
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20131002173407_1.dmp
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  9373 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-861c8f22-4970-4dab-90b5-c79ad2131002
```

what do I do? I reinstalled it twice it downloaded some 200 MB update and still didn't start...every time I open it it opens update window and closes.

My laptop specifications:

- i5 3230 M
- 4gb ram
- Intel HD 4000 graphics

Answer (score 1):

```
Major opcode of failed request: 18 (X_ChangeProperty)
```

is usually caused by a locale issue. See [issue 1420](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/1420)

You quickly check if this is the problem by running:

```
LC_ALL=C steam
```

If this is your problem, set LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in /etc/default/locale

Answer (score 0):

First of, since you didn't mention which way you uninstalled steam, try fully purging it from your system

```
sudo apt-get purge steam*
```

Then try installing it again, by downloading .deb package from the website http://store.steampowered.com/about/?snr=1_4_4__11

If that didn't fix the issue, try deleting appcache folder in the

```
/home/.local/share/Steam/Appcache
```

Just delete entire folder Appcache and try logging in.